# CloudKit delete records at specific date time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

I want to delete a record in a shared cloud container at a specific date time. When the record is created I know when it should be deleted.

Is there a way to create a trigger that will handle the work for me?

The only solution I came up with is:

1. Add code to the app that will delete the records
2. Use a server application to query and delete the records

The first solution is not preferred since it won't work if the user does not start the app. The second solution seems to be "overkill".

Is there a way to register a trigger on the CloudKit dashboard?